# How can I count only specific values in tabluea?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a medal column, there are 4 different values in the medal column gold, silver,bronze, and NA, I don't want to count the NA column in the calculated field in tableau

I want to do something like this

Count(Medals(not including NA))/count(Medals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is

```
SUM(INT([Medal] <> “NA”)) / COUNT(“*”)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to exclude NA, Try to use this:

```
IF ISNULL([medal: NA]) THEN [medal] END
```

nb. if table name is medal, and expression are gold, silver,bronze, and NA

then you can use count